# How to get value of TDBLookupComboBox?

Tags: delphi

I have tables on my database `Tb_barang` and `Tb_jenis`. `Tb_jenis` the following columns `kd_jenis` (primary key) and `jenis`. I use `TDBLookupComboBox` to show the items from the `Tb_jenis` table. There are 6 items (Mie, Susu, etc). I want to save item selected as kd_jenis not jenis.

How to I save jenis in table to kd_jenis?

```
Sample data: Tb_jenis
jenis   kd_jenis
Mie     J1
Susu    J2
```

Here it the code I've tried.

```
if (kd.Text='') or (jenis.Text='Pilih')  then
  ShowMessage('Data Tidak Lengkap, Silakkan Dilengkapi !')
else
begin
  with dm.Qbarang do 
  begin 
    sql.Clear;
    SQL.Add('select * from Tb_barang where kd_barang='+quotedstr(kd.text)+'');
    open;
  end;
  if DM.Qbarang.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 then
    ShowMessage('Data Sudah Ada, Silakkan Isi Yang Lain!')
  else
  begin
    try
      DM.koneksi.BeginTrans;
      with DM.QU do
      begin
        close;
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('insert into Tb_barang values('+QuotedStr(kd.Text)+','
                +QuotedStr(jenis.Text)+')');
        ExecSQL;
      end;
      DM.koneksi.CommitTrans;
      ShowMessage('Data Berhasil Disimpan');
    except 
      DM.Qbarang.Close;
      DM.Qbarang.Open;
      FormShow(sender);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I've cleaned up the code formatting in your question. **TIP**: A tiny bit of effort to use decent indentation will save you hours of debugging. Not to mention that when you ask others to help you while providing horrendously unreadable code, you're going to get a negative reaction.

Comment: That said, now that I can read your code: your question doesn't make sense. The code you've provided has nothing to do with a `TDBComboBox`.

Comment: General problems with your code: (1) You're hiding errors with your exception handler. (2) You're not rolling back your explicit transaction on error, so transaction stays open. (3) You don't need explicit transaction control for single statement queries. (4) When using try..except for transactions, the `BeginTrans` should go _before_ **try** (5) Your method is doing way too much. You need to break things down into smaller reusable methods. (6) The **with** construct was great for Pascal, but is not well suited to Delphi. You **will** get bitten by obscure mistakes if you continue using it.

Comment: Thank you. 
My codes work. But I wanna change jenis to kd_jenis when it's saved to database.

Comment: If your code ***works*** then why are you here? But more to the point: Your code works in the scenarios you _have tested_. There are scenarios and cases you haven't yet tested where it ***won't work***. Finally, on the question of code that works being "good enough": If you don't mind wasting days debugging obscure defects because your code is badly written, or taking days to implement small new features that should take minutes - then by all means, carry on...

Comment: And saying you "**want to** change jenis to kd_jenis" still doesn't explain what your code has to do with `TDBLookupComboBox`? Your code is using "_non-data-aware_" techniques, but all the `TDB...` controls are intended for ***data-aware*** techniques. So it looks like the completely incorrect control to use.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to get Key Value of table from DBLookupComboBox.
so in it is 2 important property in DBLookupComboBox ListField and KeyField
if you set them correctly For Example KeyField set as kd_jenis and List Field Set as jenis then you will see Jenis on List and you can access to jenis in DBLookupCombobox.text and also you can access to KeyField (in this case kd_jenis) by DBLookupCombobox.KeyValue

Comment: I don't know how to use dblookupcombobox at all. Can you show to me how to implementation syntax for dblookupcombobox of my code above...??

Comment: @Sufi  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Displaying_and_Editing_Data_in_Lookup_List_and_Combo_Boxes

Comment: Thank you,, but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with DBLookupComboBox you may use normal combobox and fill it like the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597682/delphi-filling-combobox-items-from-sql-database/24618984#24618984).

Answer (score 0):

you should fallow this steps.

1. Put a TADOConnection to your form for connecting to a database.
2. build connection string for connecting to Database.
3. add a ADO table to your form.
4. Set Connection property to AdoConnection1(Default Name Of ADOCOnnection).
5. On ADOTable open the Table name Property and select One of your database table and then set active property as true.
6. Add a DataSource to your form and set Dataset Property as ADOTable1(Default Name of ADOTable)
7. Add DBLookupCombobox to your form and Set ListSource as DataSource1(the default name of datasource)
8. Open ListField Property and Select witch field do you want to show in Combobox.
9. Open the keyField Property and Select witch field is Key field.

All of above Steps should done at Design time. for testing your application add to edit box on your form as edit1 and edit2 then write a small code for OnCloseUp Evwnt of DBLookupCombobox like this

`Edit1.Text:=DBLookUpCombobox1.KeyValue; 
 Edit2.Text:=DBLookupCombobox1.Text;`

Comment: Don't add a new answer. Rather edit your original answer. The only time to provide a separate answer to the same question is if it differs fundamentally from your first one.

Answer (score 0):

After someone selects something in your DBLookupComboBox...The cursor to the table is moved.

You can access the value directly:

```
jenis.ListSource.DataSet.FieldByName('kd_jenis').AsString
```

This assumes that jenis is a TDBLookupComboBox.
That ListSource.DataSet points to Tb_jenis.

As Craig stated...you have a serious bug in your code...you need a RollbackTrans on exception...other wise you will never release the lock...

```
  DM.koneksi.CommitTrans;
  ShowMessage('Data Berhasil Disimpan');
except
  DM.koneksi.RollbackTrans; 
  DM.Qbarang.Close;
  DM.Qbarang.Open;
  FormShow(sender);
end;
```

I do something like this...if I need to guarantee saving info and rolling back if fails.

```
procedure TForm8.SaveData;
begin
  Assert(not ADOQuery1.Connection.InTransaction, 'Code problem-We should not be in a Transaction');
  ADOQuery1.Connection.BeginTrans;
  try
    ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
    ADOQuery1.Connection.CommitTrans;        
  finally
    if ADOQuery1.Connection.InTransaction then
    begin
      {If you are here...your in an ErrorState...and didn't Commit your Transaction}
      ADOQuery1.Connection.RollbackTrans;
      HandleError(ADOQuery1);
    end;
  end;
end;
```